# Is this an F below middle C? (check my relative pitch estimation plus my math)

Tags: tuning, intervals, relative-pitch

I'm listening to a "tone" and estimating its frequency and need some help checking both my relative pitch estimation and my math.

In this [noisy part of this video](https://youtu.be/GhsZUZmJvaM?t=343) the Mars helicopter [Ingenuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Helicopter_Ingenuity) is taking off and then hovers in a Mars atmosphere simulation chamber. The air pressure is roughly 1% of Earth's standard atmosphere but the microphone still picks up the sound nicely.

I've played A440 from [another video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LxtrLizkrU) and from that I estimate that the frequency once it reaches a stable hover is an octave plus a major third below it, or "F below middle C".

That frequency would then be 440 / 2 / 2^(1/3) or about 174.6 Hz.

Have I done this correctly?

[image: Ingenuity Mars helicopter F below middle C?]

Comment: In the clip, there are two different shots fairly close after one another. In the first shot, which corresponds to the image you've posted, the tone I'm hearing is an Eb, and yes, I'd say the fundamental is the Eb below middle C – though I'm sure people who are posting full answers will consider the physics involved in this in much more detail. In the second shot shortly after that I also hear the tone as an F, and I'm willing to suppose the fundamental is the F below middle C.

Comment: Is the tone strong enough (SNR) that a typical smartphone tuner app could tell you the frequency?  Or maybe try running an FFT on the source?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That's a great idea! I used o be able to download YouTubes with [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43159565/3904031) and then extract the audio with [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62163/5334) or [ffmpeg](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/327177/143729) but they've changed the way that YouTube videos download and so my script no longer works. If you know a way to get the audio as a .wav or similar file then the FFT is easy in Python. I don't use apps on my phone or download third party programs if I can help it (ffmpeg was an exception).

Comment: @uhoh  possibly   https://ytmp3.cc/en13/   or  https://x2convert.com/en20/download-youtube-to-mp3-music .  I haven't tried those; used to use some similar service successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually an octave below where you say, it starts off in the first shot at about an Eb and then in the second shot when it lifts off it goes up to about an F an octave and a 5th below middle C. That would put the frequencies at approximately 78 hz and 87 hz respectively. Your math seems right but you are an octave high on the pitch, 174/2=87.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wonder if there is a strong first harmonic and I'm listening on a laptop with a poor low frequency response, so I missed the fundamental.  The rotor is *nominally* 2400 RPM or ~40 per second, and so for each blade the tips pass ~80 times a second, but there are two blades at 90 degrees which are not necessarily identical in all parameters (and sound reflections may be different for each) so there can be strength at both ~80 and ~160 Hz. This is why I asked here where people with better ears than mine can help sort it out.

Comment: @uhoh I compared the sounds to notes on my electric bass and the fundamentals are low frequencies, approximately Eb and F on the 1st and 3rd frets of the D string. As with most sounds and recordings there are also a lot of overtones mixed in.